# Query unique values for categories/transactions

Tags: sql, grouping, hana, having, distinct-values

I would like to query a database table that contains data like this for the distinct articleIDs in each transaction:

```
TransactionID   TransactPos   ArticleID
```

```
1               1             Article A
1               2             Article B
2               1             Article A
2               2             Article B
3               1             Article A
3               2             Article C
3               3             Article D 
3               4             Article E      <---
3               5             Article E      <---
3               6             Article E      <---
3               7             Article F      
4               1             Article A      <---
4               2             Article A      <---
4               3             Article C
```

What I want as a result are only **distinct values for each transaction**

So, the desired results would look like this:

```
TransactionID   TransactPos   ArticleID
```

```
1               1             Article A
1               2             Article B
2               1             Article A
2               2             Article B
3               1             Article A
3               2             Article C
3               3             Article D 
3            4/5/6            Article E      <--- Distinct value for Transaction 3
3               7             Article F      
4              1/2            Article A      <--- Distinct value for Transaction 4
4               3             Article C
```

Is anybody having an idea? I tried around with distinct and group by's, but I had no luck so far.

Comment: I don't get how you are defining "unique value".

Comment: where is `Article E`???  how come is will be escaped with distinct

Comment: Maybe the term distinct values is better...

Comment: @Rams: See, the Article E exists three times in transaction 3. What I want is that the article is only returned once.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Given data is in distinct with those 3 columns and if you want to get the output as you mentioned. Try below query to get the same

```
  select TransactionID , string_agg(TransactPos, '/') as TransactPos,   ArticleID   from yourtable 
    group by TransactionID,ArticleID
```

Comment: And for the altered request `string_agg(TransactPos, '/')` instead of `min(TransactPos)`.

Comment: @ThorstenKettner yeah changed accordingly

Comment: That wasn't even necessary, I just added it for clarification ;-). But your solution works like a charm, thanks!